# Error Opening Access Database with C# Application

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledbconnection

I'm updating a C# (.NET 3.5) application to interact with an Access database, but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: Unrecognized database format

This is the code I'm using to open a connection to the database:

```
        String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
            "Data Source=" + filePath;

        try
        {
            this.conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            this.conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

I know that the file path is correct.  I suspect that the `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;` is incorrect.  How do I find out what the database format is?  I did not make the database in question, but I do have read-access to it.  Thanks.

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add Data Source , user/password parametters . You can see http://connectionstrings.com/access